# How do I intercept all commands and packets sent from OpenCL host to the processor ?

Tags: gcc, opencl

I want to find out how do i get a list of all the commands that the OpenCL host sends to the processor when we run our openCL code.

Currently i'm running my code using a gcc compiler. Is there any way that i can use that compiler to extract all the commands being sent ?

Comment: FYI you, shouldn't have edited my answer to add: "My laptop has an Intel processor and Intel HD graphic card". However, that is VERY relevant information: I don't know whether it is possible to intercept OpenCL commands on an APU.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [CodeXL](https://gpuopen.com/compute-product/codexl/).
It was developed by AMD. However, it should work with both AMD and NVIDIA GPUs.

Answer (score 1):

NVIDIA Visual Nsight records OpenCL API calls, at least on Windows.

Comment: I believe it dumps everything to a data file you might be able to parse, or let Nsight view it for you.

Comment: I'm currently using the AMD APP SDK to provide the openCL platform for my laptop which has an Intel processor and Intel HD graphics card. The AMD SDK works fine for running openCL but for debugging, CodeXL and NVIDIA VIsual Nsight both require an AMD or Nvidia GPU and do not work in my case.

Comment: Nsight works with any GPU, to just capture API calls.

Comment: If instead of using the GPU I use my CPU, will it still capture the commands sent ?

Comment: Yes, I think so.